# Why WPF has thread affinity

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I was reading the wpf dispatcher object.
It says wpf has thread affinity.
I am not able to understand why wpf is designed this way.
Can someone please explain me here.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8733393/1136211

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do UI Controls in WPF have Thread Affinity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733303/why-do-ui-controls-in-wpf-have-thread-affinity)