# RadGridView Dynamic adding Columns and ColumnGroups thread issue

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview, dynamic-columns

I'm trying to create grid with static and dynamic columns.
Dynamic columns should be under ColumnGroups.
When I'm not using ColumnGroups everything works ok. But when I try to assign dynamic column to one of groups I get

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

I create new window in separate thread

```
Thread newWindowThread=new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            var instrumentWindow=new InstrumentWindow();
            ((InstrumentWindowViewModel)instrumentWindow.DataContext).Initialize(instrument.ToString(),DateTime.Today);
            instrumentWindow.Show();
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }));

        newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;

        newWindowThread.Start();
```

After I create static columns

```
this.EventGrid.Columns.Add(new GridViewDataColumn()
        {
            Header = "Time",
            DataMemberBinding = new Binding("Time"),
            DataType = typeof(DateTime)
        });
```

And actually function which is responsible for creating dynamic columns

Basically the idea is to create ColumnGroup for each term and under that group display term properties.

```
    private void InitDynamicColumns()
    {
        var maxTermCount = ((InstrumentWindowViewModel)this.DataContext).Events.Max(x => x.Terms.Length);
        var termHeaders = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < maxTermCount; i++)
        {
            var currentTerm = ((InstrumentWindowViewModel)this.DataContext).Events.First().Terms[i];
            var analyzerAmountType = currentTerm.Type == AnalyzerAmountType.Seconds ? "sec" : "ticks";
            this.EventGrid.ColumnGroups.Add(new GridViewColumnGroup
            {
                Header = currentTerm.Size + " " + analyzerAmountType + " term",
                Name = currentTerm.Size + analyzerAmountType + "term"
            });

            termHeaders.Add(currentTerm.Size + analyzerAmountType + "term");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < maxTermCount; i++)
        {
            this.EventGrid.Columns.Add(new GridViewDataColumn()
            {
                Header = "Property1",
                DataMemberBinding = new Binding("Terms[" + i + "].Property1"),
                 ColumnGroupName = termHeaders[i]
            });
            this.EventGrid.Columns.Add(new GridViewDataColumn()
            {
                Header = "Property2",
                DataMemberBinding = new Binding("Terms[" + i + "].Property2"),
                  ColumnGroupName = termHeaders[i]
            });
            this.EventGrid.Columns.Add(new GridViewDataColumn()
            {
                Header = "Property3",
                DataMemberBinding = new Binding("Terms[" + i + "].Property3"),
                 ColumnGroupName = termHeaders[i]
            });
        }

    }
```

When I don't use ColumnGroups everything works as expected.But when I try to assig ColumnGroup to Column I get this Thread exception.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create the window on one thread and the columns on another one if you indend to display the columns in a control within that window.

Just forget about this because it doesn't work because of the thread affinity:

[Why do UI Controls in WPF have Thread Affinity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733303/why-do-ui-controls-in-wpf-have-thread-affinity)

You must create the window on the same thread as the one on which you create the columns and this is typically the main (UI) thread.

A WPF control may only be accessed on the thread on which it was originally created.

Comment: Don't think it is the reason.As I do all manipulation with control in ModalWindow code behind.
And for dynamic columns everything works perfect.It starts failing when I try to create and assign ColumnGroup.
And this is strange

Comment: Don't Think what is the reason? Why are you creating a window on a background thread in the first place? Obviously you won't get any cross-threading errors if you create all controls on the same thread.

Comment: I need to create several independent windows from main window.
And each window will be getting independent data not blocking main window

Comment: Again: You *cannot* create a UI object on one thread and then use it in a control that was created on another thread. Just because you "don't think it is the reason" this doesn't change I am afraid.

Comment: In that case why it works fine for dynamic columns?and fails for groups?

Maybe you have any suggestions?not only criticising?)

Comment: I am not criticising, I am telling you why you are getting the exception. It is because you create a UI object on one thread and then try to access it on another one.

Comment: Sorry.I pretty new on this site.I voted on your reply and marked it as answer.
Can you suggest how to better solve this problem?
I understand that I create Modal from Main window.But I don't know how to solve this situation another way.I still need those independant windows.

Comment: I am afraid there is no way to create an interactive element on one thread and then use it another thread. I am not sure whay you are actually trying to do here and what is "blocking" the main window. You should perform any long-running code on a *background* thread but this shouldn't involve any UI controls. They are always created on the UI thread.

Comment: I'm trying create new STA thread where Modal window will be running.It has it's ViewModel which loads data for this window.
Because when I create Window not in new thread it disables Main window and it shouldn't.

Comment: Nevermind.I found a solution.I didn't need another thread at all.
Whole that "blocking" thing why I created new thread is fixed by using Show() instead ShowDialog() methods :)
Thank you again for trying to help)